# How to save in a Javascript variable information from PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I want to do a page were a user can connect with a teacher in order to ask a question from a subject. The thing is that I I´ve been searching the web but I couldn´t find a way to store in a JavaScript variabl (var name = .....) information that I have recieved from PHP ($.get( "LINK PHP",function( data ) {}).

Thanks in advance.

```js
$.get("LINK PHP", function(data) {

  var divProfesores = $('#profesores');
  for (var profesor of data) {
    var ficha_profesor = `<div id="products" class="row list-group"><div class="item  col-xs-4 col-lg-4"><div class="thumbnail"><img class="group list-group-image" src="../IMAGENES/logo final.png" alt="" /><div class="caption"><h4 class="group inner list-group-item-heading">${info_profesor}</h4><p id="nom">${profesor.nombre}</p><p id="tel">${profesor.telefono}</p><p class="group inner list-group-item-text">${profesor.descripcion}</p><div class="row"><div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6"><p class="lead"></p></div><div id="con"><button class="btn waves-effect waves-light#80cbc4 teal lighten-3" type="button" onclick="conectar('${profesor.id}')">Conectar</button></div></div></div></div></div>`
    divProfesores.append(ficha_profesor)
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="products" class="row list-group">
  <div class="item  col-xs-4 col-lg-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img class="group list-group-image" src="../IMAGENES/logofinal.png" alt="" />
      <div class="caption">
        <h4 class="group inner list-group-item-heading">
          Teacher basic Info:</h4>
        <div id="infoprof">

        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
            <p class="lead">
            </p>
          </div>
          <div id="con">
            <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light#80cbc4 teal lighten-3" id="id" type="button">Conect with Teacher</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: If you're using `$.get`, it is already in a variable in the callback (in your case, `data`).

Answer (score 0):

Write the javascript out using php... Something like this... been a while since I did php but remember php is server side and js happens after the page is rendered, in this use case.

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>
        <?php 
          echo "let professorId ='".$profId."'";
        ?>
    </script>
```